# Unable to activate USB 3.0 on HP ProBook 4530s Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, usb-3

Whenever I attach my USB 3.0 Flash Drive, it shows a message stating that my device can perform better if I connect it to Super Speed USB 3.0 port. I have installed the proper drivers (see the attached image). My notebook do have USB 3.0 port.

[image: Installed Drives]

Comment: Maybe you still attaching it to a USB 2.0 port, maybe try with the other ports.

Comment: @user532986 Are you connecting it to Blue Port ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I am attaching it to Blue Port.

Comment: @KiraSan I tried all ports.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not support USB 3.0 natively, which means that you need to have  an XHCI controller in order to get 3.0 speeds. Go into UEFI/BIOS and search for XHCI Hand-Off and enable it. Also make sure that XHCI Mode is not disabled.

Comment: I can't find XHCI Hand-Off in BIOS. Notebook motherboard is HP 167c. I can't find this setting under USB Legacy Support (as other people find it there) or any place.